# How to fix compressai "subprocess-exited-with-error"?

Tags: python, pip, subprocess, python-wheel

During `pip install compressai` I faced `subprocess-exited-with-error` just after upgrading my `pip` version to `pip==22.3`. It is worth mentioning that before upgrading `pip` downgrading the `pip` would not fix my problem as `compressai` needs the last version of `pip`. Can anyone help me solve this problem? My OS is windows and I'm running the command through gitbash.

```
Collecting compressai
  Using cached compressai-1.2.1.tar.gz (72 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [48 lines of output]
  fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  running egg_info
  writing compressai.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to compressai.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to compressai.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to compressai.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'compressai.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\mg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\mg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\mg\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 122, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 308, in run
      self.find_sources()
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 316, in find_sources
      mm.run()
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 560, in run
      self.add_defaults()
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 604, in add_defaults
      self.read_manifest()
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 209, in read_manifest
      self.filelist.append(line)
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 497, in append
      path = convert_path(item)
    File "C:\Users\MG\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9gpf42j3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\util.py", line 139, in convert_path
      raise ValueError("path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname)
  ValueError: path '/home/runner/work/CompressAI/CompressAI/compressai/cpp_exts/ops/ops.cpp' cannot be absolute
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```